# How to use awk shell script to compare and match two files

Tags: shell, awk

Basically, I have two files

dupestest.txt

```
152,153
192,193
215,216
290,291
2279,2280
2282,2283
```

haftest.txt

```
152,ABBOTS ROAD
153,ABBOTS ROAD
154,ABBOTS ROAD
155,ABBOTS ROAD
156,ABBOTS ROAD
157,ABBOTS ROAD
```

I want to find the numbers in dupestest.txt in haftest.txt and produce this outcome: results.txt

```
152,ABBOTS ROAD,153 ABBOTS ROAD 
192,ABBOTS ROAD,193,ABBOTS ROAD
```

etc

Can anyone give me any advice?

It has to be in awk.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have just been looking online for answers, I am very new to AWK and I have seen alot of command line answers but I want it in a script

Comment: Basically, the command line and a script is nearly equal. You can just put the command line into a file and try to run it.

Comment: But I have yet to find a command line that works, thats why I am asking here for some advice

Comment: In your real data is $2 always the same in haftest? for example would you have different values for 152 and 153?

Comment: Yes they sometimes will be different values. For example 152 could be abbots rd and 153 could be abbots road.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a || $2 in a{print $1, a[$1], $2, a[$2]}' haftest.txt dupestest.txt
```

This line of script tests if either the first or the second key in `dupestest.txt` exists in `haftest.txt`, and prints its associated value in `dupestest.txt` if one of the keys exists, you may have to tweak the script a little bit if only one of the two keys exists in `haftest.txt` to get the desired output, that's left as an exercise for you.

Comment: Nice. I was wondering how to get rid of the spaces in output with `print` - you did that with `OFS=","`

Comment: @user2428639, this script runs perfectly here with your supplied sample data. Well, I will not help you further, because I don't see that you are trying yourself, I don't even see any useful error messages when you say `giving parse error`, now you are on your own.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a&&$2 in a{print a[$1]","a[$2]}' haft.txt dup.txt
```